# Convert Map<A, Map<B, C>> to Map<B, Map<A, C>> using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have structure map of maps like:

```
Map<Center, Map<Product, Value>> given
```

and I want to get

```
Map<Product, Map<Center, Value>> result
```

I've used Java streams

```
Map<Product, Map<Center, Value>> result = given.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue()
                 .entrySet().stream()
                 .map(e -> Triple(entry.getKey(), e.getKey(), e.getValue())))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Triple::getProduct,
                    Collectors.toMap(Triple::getCenter, Triple::getValue)));
```

where `Triple` is simple value class. My questions is if it is possible to do it functional without using additional classes like `Triple` or e.g. `Table` from guava?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn what kinds of questions are appropriate for this site.  If you can [edit] your question to fit the requirements of this site, please do so.

Comment: why exactly do you want to avoid mapping to an intermediate object i.e. `Triple`? seems just fine as is.

Comment: Because I'm creating this class only to use in two lines. I think is no bad, but maybe it is possible better :) I can use `Tuple` for vavr.io too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you want to proceed with your stream approach it's *unavoidable* to create some type of intermediate object i.e. `Triple`, or `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` or any other type applicable.

You're essentially looking for something like C#'s anonymous types i.e. you could just map to

```
new { k1 = entry.getKey(), k2 = e.getKey(), k3 = e.getValue()) }
```

and then immediately access those in the `groupingBy` and `toMap` phase.

Java has something *similar but not quite* i.e. you could do:

```
Map<Product, Map<Center, Value>> result = 
           given.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue()
                        .entrySet().stream()
                        .map(e -> new Object() {
                            Center c = entry.getKey();
                            Product p = e.getKey();
                            Value v = e.getValue();
                        }))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.p, Collectors.toMap(o -> o.c, o -> o.v)));
```

*credit goes to @shmosel.*

The only benefit here being you don't need to predefine a custom class.

Comment: Why do you say there's no type inference?

Comment: @shmosel probably the wrong wording there. edited to be more specific.

Comment: It's not true though. The anonymous type is inferred and you can access its fields.

Comment: @shmosel not that i know of, so would be cool to be shown how you can group by `k2` and access `k1` and `k3` in the `toMap`

Comment: @shmosel something new learnt today :). my first time actually using this syntax in java `new Object() { .... }` so all credit goes to you. thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Some things are easier done without streams:

```
Map<Product, Map<Center, Value>> result = new HashMap<>();
given.forEach((c, pv) -> pv.forEach((p, v) ->
        result.computeIfAbsent(p, k -> new HashMap<>()).put(c, v)));
```